# accessing data from file path with"space" on windows

Tags: c, windows

I'm facing a weird problem on windows
I'm using a library called STDCL which runs pretty well on linux,but on windows there is an error if the output .exe file path got "spaces"

example:

```
c:\my file\my file.exe //won't work
c:\my_file\my file.exe //will work
c:\my file\my file.exe //won't work
// and it is accessing data from dll(any where) containing STDCL library
c:\my_file\my file.exe //will work
// and it is accessing data from dll(any where) containing STDCL library
```

I got the source code to compile the library
or is there an easier way to force accepting the path of the .exe inside my .dll

edit: sample code

```
/* hello_stdcl.c */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdcl.h>

int main()
{
    stdcl_init(); // this is only necessary for Windows

   cl_uint n = 64;

#if(1)

    /* use default contexts, if no GPU use CPU */
   CLCONTEXT* cp = (stdgpu)? stdgpu : stdcpu;

   unsigned int devnum = 0;

   void* clh = clopen(cp,"matvecmult.cl",CLLD_NOW);
   cl_kernel krn = clsym(cp,clh,"matvecmult_kern",0);

   /* allocate OpenCL device-sharable memory */
   cl_float* aa = (float*)clmalloc(cp,n*n*sizeof(cl_float),0);
   cl_float* b = (float*)clmalloc(cp,n*sizeof(cl_float),0);
   cl_float* c = (float*)clmalloc(cp,n*sizeof(cl_float),0);

   clndrange_t ndr = clndrange_init1d( 0, n, 64);

   /* initialize vectors a[] and b[], zero c[] */
   int i,j; 
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) for(j=0;j<n;j++) aa[i*n+j] = 1.1f*i*j;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) b[i] = 2.2f*i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++) c[i] = 0.0f;

   /* define the computational domain and workgroup size */
   //clndrange_t ndr = clndrange_init1d( 0, n, 64);

   /* non-blocking sync vectors a and b to device memory (copy to GPU)*/
   clmsync(cp,devnum,aa,CL_MEM_DEVICE|CL_EVENT_NOWAIT);
   clmsync(cp,devnum,b,CL_MEM_DEVICE|CL_EVENT_NOWAIT);

   /* set the kernel arguments */
   clarg_set(cp,krn,0,n);
   clarg_set_global(cp,krn,1,aa);
   clarg_set_global(cp,krn,2,b);
   clarg_set_global(cp,krn,3,c);

   /* non-blocking fork of the OpenCL kernel to execute on the GPU */
   clfork(cp,devnum,krn,&ndr,CL_EVENT_NOWAIT);

   /* non-blocking sync vector c to host memory (copy back to host) */
   clmsync(cp,0,c,CL_MEM_HOST|CL_EVENT_NOWAIT);

   /* force execution of operations in command queue (non-blocking call) */
   clflush(cp,devnum,0);

   /* block on completion of operations in command queue */
   clwait(cp,devnum,CL_ALL_EVENT);

   for(i=0;i<n;i++) printf("%d %f %f\n",i,b[i],c[i]);

   clfree(aa);
   clfree(b);
   clfree(c);

   clclose(cp,clh);

#endif

    system("pause");

}
```

edit 2:

when I compile the code above ...take the result .exe file and put it in a path without spaces (short path) it works

if I put it in a path with spaces ...it simply crashes and when I debugged it was like memory issue (so it crashes with long path)

when I contacted the library creator he told me:
"windows getcwd() call returns an unusable path with spaces"

as I told before this library works fine on Linux,what may be the solution for this on Windows

system: win7 64 bit

Comment: Show the code how you are passing those strings to the related functions?

Comment: If possible, don't reinvent the wheel, use boost Filesystem!!!

Comment: Or use [`GetShortPathName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx).

Comment: check edit for example code

Comment: @RemyLebeau does that work even if disable8dot3 is set in the current control set of the registry? Genuinely curious.

Comment: sorry for not putting the example code at first time,as the code itself doesn't matter
the whole problem happens once i use the library itself for outputting the .exe file or .dll file
accessing the .exe file or .dll file from a "space" path makes error

Comment: @WhozCraig: no, GetShortPathName() will fail if 8.3 filenames are disabled on the filesystem.

Comment: I accidentally deleted my original comment which was longer. Sounds like you're using `system` to launch the application. If so, wrap the filename in quotes. `system` only parses up to the first space to determine which application to launch.

Comment: This is C code, not C++ as e.g. Hugo Corrá assumed. I removed the misleading C++ tag. That said, you claim there is "an error" but you don't say which error and when. It would be good if you explained what you did in small steps, described what happened and what you expected to happen. As a last step, you can add your interpretations of these facts, but that's secondary.

Comment: well I putted C++ because the library simply a C++ library ...
check edits for more info about the problem

Answer (score 2):

Use quates for the binary name/path as "my file.exe"